# poi ms-word Can you make a table in the table?

Tags: java, apache-poi

Can you make a table in the compartment inside the table like case 2?
Can you make a table in the compartment inside the table like case 2?

[image]

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S6IeL.png)

```
public class PoiTest3 {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        try (XWPFDocument doc = new XWPFDocument()) {

            XWPFTable table = doc.createTable();

            //Creating first Row
            XWPFTableRow row1 = table.getRow(0);
            row1.getCell(0).setText("First Row, First Column");
            row1.addNewTableCell().setText("First Row, Second Column");
            row1.addNewTableCell().setText("First Row, Third Column");

            //Creating second Row
            XWPFTableRow row2 = table.createRow();
            row2.getCell(0).setText("Second Row, First Column");
            row2.getCell(1).setText("Second Row, Second Column");
            row2.getCell(2).setText("Second Row, Third Column");

            //create third row
            XWPFTableRow row3 = table.createRow();
            row3.getCell(0).setText("Third Row, First Column");
            row3.getCell(1).setText("Third Row, Second Column");
            row3.getCell(2).setText("Third Row, Third Column");

            // save to .docx file
            try (FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream("c:\\excel\\table.docx")) {
                doc.write(out);
            }

        }

    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[XWPFTableCell](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/dev/org/apache/poi/xwpf/usermodel/XWPFTableCell.html) is a [IBody](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/dev/org/apache/poi/xwpf/usermodel/IBody.html). So it provides [XWPFTable insertNewTbl(org.apache.xmlbeans.XmlCursor cursor)](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/dev/org/apache/poi/xwpf/usermodel/IBody.html#insertNewTbl-org.apache.xmlbeans.XmlCursor-). So yes, it is possible to add a table into a table cell.

But the usage of that `org.apache.xmlbeans.XmlCursor` is not well documented.

To create that cursor we need the table cell, the cursor shall be in,  and an new empty paragrsph in that cell. The empty paragrsph is needed because all content we insert using that cursor will be before the element the cursor points to. So that element should be an empty paragraph to avoid inserting content into existing elements like paragraphs with content or other content containing elements.

The following shows the simplest possible complete example.

```
import java.io.FileOutputStream;

import org.apache.poi.xwpf.usermodel.*;

public class CreateWordTableInTable {
    
 public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

  try (XWPFDocument doc = new XWPFDocument()) {

   //create main table
   XWPFTable table = doc.createTable();

   //create rows and cells
   XWPFTableRow row = table.getRow(0);
   row.getCell(0).setText("Main table A1");
   row.addNewTableCell().setText("Main table B1");
   row.addNewTableCell().setText("Main table C1");
   row = table.createRow();
   row.getCell(0).setText("Main table A2");
   row.getCell(1).setText("Main table B2");
   row.getCell(2).setText("Main table C2");
   
   
   //create inner table
   //we need the first table cell and an new empty paragrsph in that first cell
   row = table.getRow(0);
   XWPFTableCell cell = row.getTableCells().get(0);
   XWPFParagraph paragraph = cell.addParagraph();
   //now we can insert a table there
   org.apache.xmlbeans.XmlCursor cursor = paragraph.getCTP().newCursor();
   XWPFTable innerTable = cell.insertNewTbl(cursor);
   //set table borders
   innerTable.setTopBorder(XWPFTable.XWPFBorderType.SINGLE, 4, 0, "000000");
   innerTable.setRightBorder(XWPFTable.XWPFBorderType.SINGLE, 4, 0, "000000");
   innerTable.setBottomBorder(XWPFTable.XWPFBorderType.SINGLE, 4, 0, "000000");
   innerTable.setLeftBorder(XWPFTable.XWPFBorderType.SINGLE, 4, 0, "000000");
   innerTable.setInsideHBorder(XWPFTable.XWPFBorderType.SINGLE, 4, 0, "000000");
   innerTable.setInsideVBorder(XWPFTable.XWPFBorderType.SINGLE, 4, 0, "000000");
   //create rows and cells
   XWPFTableRow rowInInnerTable = innerTable.createRow();
   XWPFTableCell cellInInnerTable = rowInInnerTable.createCell();
   cellInInnerTable.setText("Inner table A1");
   cellInInnerTable = rowInInnerTable.createCell();
   cellInInnerTable.setText("Inner table B1");
   cellInInnerTable = rowInInnerTable.createCell();
   cellInInnerTable.setText("Inner table C1");
   rowInInnerTable = innerTable.createRow();
   cellInInnerTable = rowInInnerTable.getCell(0);
   cellInInnerTable.setText("Inner table A2");
   cellInInnerTable = rowInInnerTable.getCell(1);
   cellInInnerTable.setText("Inner table B2");
   cellInInnerTable = rowInInnerTable.getCell(2);
   cellInInnerTable.setText("Inner table C2");
    
   //save to .docx file
   try (FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream("./CreateWordTableInTable.docx")) {
    doc.write(out);
   }
  }
 }
}
```

It produces:

[image]

This code is tested an works using the current Apache POI version 5.2.3. Download: https://poi.apache.org/download.html#POI-5.2.3. Needed components see https://poi.apache.org/components/index.html#components.

Comment: Thank you. Which JAR should I use for the error?

innerTable.setTopBorder(XWPFTable.XWPFBorderType.SINGLE, 4, 0, "000000");
innerTable.setRightBorder(XWPFTable.XWPFBorderType.SINGLE, 4, 0, "000000");
innerTable.setBottomBorder(XWPFTable.XWPFBorderType.SINGLE, 4, 0, "000000");
innerTable.setLeftBorder(XWPFTable.XWPFBorderType.SINGLE, 4, 0, "000000");

Comment: This code is tested an works using the current Apache POI version 5.2.3. Download: https://poi.apache.org/download.html#POI-5.2.3. Needed components see https://poi.apache.org/components/index.html#components.